# Another Word Wrapping question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, word-wrap

I have been searching for a solution for the past two days now. I am working with asp.net and certain text from a form gets saved to a database. When pulling the text back from the database I want to display it in a div or label or whatever it really doesn't matter, but I want to recognize the line breaks that were saved and text wrap it in the corner. I thought I had it when I did word-wrap:break-word; and white-space:pre; but then I realized that words got split in two going from one line to the next.

I know that this can be solved with javascript. Is there any way I can do this without having to use javascript or jquery? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a helper for this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString FormatText(this HtmlHelper html, string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        // you could use any line break you might have in your text to split
        var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(
            string.Join("<br/>", lines.Select(line => html.Encode(line)))
        );
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<div>
    @Html.FormatText(Model.SomeText)
</div>
```